# cannot update the object in CLIPS, getting compile time error in clips

Tags: clips

```
 (bind ?existing_total_count (nth$ 2 (send ?INSTANCE ?get-INTS)))
 (send (nth$ 2 (send ?INSTANCE put-INTS)) (+ ?total_count ?existing_total_count))
```

first line compiles fine, but second line throwing error
Function send expected argument #2 to be of type symbol

I cant findout what the issue is. I am trying to update the second entry in slot INTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CLIPS> 
(defclass A
   (is-a USER)
   (multislot INTS))
CLIPS> (make-instance [a] of A (INTS 1 2 3))
[a]
CLIPS> (send [a] print)
[a] of A
(INTS 1 2 3)
CLIPS> (bind ?INSTANCE [a])
[a]
CLIPS> (bind ?existing_total_count (nth$ 2 (send ?INSTANCE get-INTS)))
2
CLIPS> (bind ?total_count 3)
3
CLIPS> (slot-replace$ ?INSTANCE INTS 2 2 (+ ?total_count ?existing_total_count))
(1 5 3)
CLIPS> (send [a] print)
[a] of A
(INTS 1 5 3)
CLIPS> (bind ?total_count 5)
5
CLIPS> (send ?INSTANCE put-INTS (replace$ (send ?INSTANCE get-INTS) 2 2 (+ ?total_count ?existing_total_count)))
(1 7 3)
CLIPS> (send [a] print)
[a] of A
(INTS 1 7 3)
CLIPS>
```

Comment: thanks for the response.. I am not aware there is a slot-replace available.. by using slot-replace$ I see [a] got changed, does it mean bind will actually will get a reference of [a] into INSTANCE..because when we print [a] it showed 1 5 3,  and  the second way to change entries is using put-INTS with replace$?

Comment: Documentation links are here: http://www.clipsrules.net/?q=Documentation. The bound value of ?INSTANCE will not change as a result of using put-INTS.